# Style deleted posts consistently on search results page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, deleted-questions

♦ mods can see deleted posts in search results, but the posts don't show any indication that they've been deleted (e.g., see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1). It would be nice if posts on the search results page were styled the same way as deleted posts elsewhere on the site

#### Before

[image: Screenshot of the current view]

#### After

[image: Screenshot of the desired view]

Comment: Is there a request that returns both deleted and non-deleted posts? Otherwise, what's the point of coloring everything pink when the request contains `deleted:1`?

Comment: @Gilles Oh; apparently not. The point was so I could tell which posts in a search were deleted, but apparently the answer is either "all of them" or "none of them" depending on if you included `deleted:1`. Well this request just got way less useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime in the years since this question was asked, this was implemented.  Here's an example from my own posts on EL&U (where I have 10k and can thus see my deleted posts):

[image: screenshot]

Deleted posts are styled with the pink background, same as they are on the question page itself and in other places where people (usually just moderators) can see deleted content.

The `deleted:all` search parameter works for anybody who can see deleted posts, not just for moderators.  For non-moderators it shows only your own posts.  If you have any deleted posts on a site where you have that privilege, you can verify the styling.  (I'm not a moderator on EL&U, where I took that screenshot.)